# Silly confusion: how to geometrically define canonical flat metrics

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

This is perhaps a bizarre and somewhat philosophical question but nevertheless, I find it a bit confusing.

When we define $\mathbb{R}^n$ with its canonical Riemannian metric, one can go about it like this:

Any smooth manifold starts off as a set so does $\mathbb{R}^n$. To show it is a topological manifold, it is certainly enough to consider the identity map. We may then construct a smooth atlas just out of this chart and thus it is a smooth manifold.

Thus we have the tensor bundles. Since the coordinates are global, they are all trivialized by structures arising from the single chart. Thus any Riemannian metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be written

$$g= g_{ij} dx^{i} dx^{j}$$

for some smooth functions of the canonical coordinates $x^{i}$. At this point one may define the canonical Riemannian (or Lorentzian) metric by requiring $g_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$ or the Lorentzian analogue.

Yet somehow this just doesn't feel geometrical in a way; I'd like to review how an elementary notion of length on the inner product space $(\mathbb{R}^n, < \cdot , \cdot>)$ corresponds to the above trivial Riemannian geometry - particularly in the Lorentzian case.

Of course we can't use geodesic normal coordinates as we are trying to define the metric.

Comment: Start by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to show that “line segments are the shortest paths.”

Comment: Ah thank you, immediately recalled the point of this argument!

Comment: Perhaps you should post an answer to this effect when you have it figured out! :)

Comment: Yes, if I have some time later on... I suppose in the Lorentzian case, by parallelism one doesn't have a better argument than line segments have the least mechanical action. (When we restrict ourselves to timelike curves)